# How to route from outside of components with `react-router` in Electron?

Tags: react-router, electron

The problem I'm having with `react-router` in Electorn is that I can't do something like `window.location = '/'` since `window.location` in electron app points to filesystem-level path of main script.

I know the official document of `react-router` says to do like

```
// history.js
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'
export default createBrowserHistory()

// index.js
import history from './history'
render(<Router history={history}/>, el)

// actions.js
import history from './history'
history.replaceState(null, '/some/path')
```

but calling `history.replaceState()` does nothing in my app.

The most suspicious and weird part is that although I used `createBrowserHistory` for my router history `window.location` prints hashed path.

Is there any Electron specific issue with history based routing? If not, why calling `history.replaceState(null, '/')` doesn't make route changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hash history as of react-router 1.0.3:

```
// history.js
import createHashHistory from 'history/lib/createHashHistory';
export default createHashHistory();
```

Rendering:

```
// index.js
import history from './history'
render(<Router history={ history }/>, el);
```

And route as following:

```
// action.js
import history from './history';
history.replaceState(null, '/some/path');
```

Read [doc](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v1.0.3/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md) for detail.